# Claws Mail gpg uid

Tags: email, gpg

I have a gnupg keyring with three uids. When sending an email using Claws Mail the default identity (myself1@firstmail.com) is always used to sign the mail regardless of the mail account used to send the mail. Of course, I would like to sign the mail according to the account the mail was sent from.

```
/home/myself/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2018-09-05 [SC] [expires: 2022-09-04]
      MYKEYID
uid        [ ultimate ] My Self <myself1@firstmail.com>
uid        [ ultimate ] My Self <myself2@secondmail.com>
uid        [ ultimate ] My Self <myself3@thirdmail.com>
sub   rsa4096 2018-09-05 [E] [expires: 2020-09-05]
sub   rsa4096 2018-09-06 [S] [expires: 2020-09-05]
```

Therefore, I set the per account settings for gpg and S/MIME as seen below:

[image: enter image description here]]

Is this a bug or intended behavior?

Comment: It is not possible. Your question has already been answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/1017749/how-do-i-manage-multiple-e-mail-addresses-with-gnupg

Comment: It is not possible. Your question has already been answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/1017749/how-do-i-manage-multiple-e-mail-addresses-with-gnupg